# Is is possible to specify (fake) a User Agent using IIS Reverse Proxy?

Tags: .net, iis, user-agent, reverse-proxy

I've got a site that is setup using a reverse proxy in IIS. The main site on server1 sends requests to "folder" to server2. This is working as expected, with one strange exception:

The app on server2 is old. It is using code from .NET Framework 1.1 and some 3rd party controls that are, for obvious reasons, no longer supported.

When browsing server1/folder in IE (any version) random things may happen and get a 404 error fairly regularly. When browsing the site in Chrome things work just as expected. If I tell IE to use the Chrome User Agent it behaves normally as well.

What I think is happening is that one of the controls is looking at the User Agent and doing something with it and failing with the modern IE over reverse proxy. (Before reverse proxy it worked in IE). As best I can tell, the configuration on server2 is the same as it was before the move to the proxy.

So, is there a way to fake, spoof, or otherwise manipulate the User Agent when passing the request from server1 to server2?

Answer (score 1):

The solution was simple enough.

In IIS in the URL Rewrite configuration slick View Server Variables... in the right hand column. Click add and enter the name of the Server Variable - in this case HTTP_USER_AGENT.

This will allow you to use and/or modify this specific server variable during the routing process. This is the step that I had missed, or gotten wrong before. To my knowledge this can't be done in the web.config file. I'm sure there's a command line to do it, but I don't know that.

After adding HTTP_USER_AGENT to the allowed server variables list it is just a matter of setting that either through IIS or in the Web.config file add the desired value to the server variables section.

```
<rule name="..." enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="[pattern]" />
  <action type="Rewrite" url="[destination]/{R:1}" />
  <serverVariables>
    <set name="HTTP_USER_AGENT" value="[desired value]" />
  </serverVariables>
</rule>
```

Simple enough after I found out you had to "allow" the use of a server variable.

Comment: If you create the rule in iis, it is added to web.config for you. In newer IIS version, it is added to <system.webserver> - which I assume means that older versions add it into <system.web>

Comment: This is the other resource I found really useful: http://sinclairinat0r.com/2014/03/14/spoofing-ie10s-user-agent-in-iis-for-ie11-support-in-sharepoint-2013/